# Solve ODE in State-space form

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Is it possible to solve an ODE in state-space form in mathematica? Such as

```
 x'[t]=A.x[t]
```

I attempted

```
w = 2; 
T = 2 Pi/w;
a = 0.4; b = 4.0; d = 0.3;

A = T {{0, 1}, {-a - b Cos[2 t], -d}}

x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]}
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], x[0] == x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but received the error

```
NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
```

Comment: I do not know why the numerical gives these warnings, but your solutions are zero according to DSolve: `w = 2;
T = 2 Pi/w;
a = 0.4; b = 4.0; d = 0.3;
x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]}
A0 = T {{0, 1}, {-a - b Cos[2 t], -d}};
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == A0.x[t], x[0] == x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]` which gives `{{x1[t] -> 0, x2[t] -> 0}}` on V 10.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ve modified slightly your problem to one which works:

I used exact numbers

```
w = 2;
T = 2 Pi/w;
a = 4/10; b = 4; d = 3/10;

A = T {{0, 1}, {-a - b Cos[2 t], -d}}
```

I then  drop the Initial condition on derivatives 
which are redundant given the order of your equation:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], x[0] == {1, 2}},x[t] , {t, 0, 1}]
```

then I plot the result

```
 ParametricPlot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

If you insist on {0,0} as initial conditions you get  (as @nasser points out)

```
 sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], x[0] == {0, 0}}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

(*  {{x1(t)->0,x2(t)->0}} *)

### Update 2

Just for fun mathematica can write the general solution for arbitrary 
ICs

```
T=a=b=d=.;
A = T {{0, 1}, {-a - b Cos[2 t], -d}}
x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]}
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == A.x[t], 
    x[0] == {a1,a2}}, x[t], t] // 
  FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! No need for {0,0}, I just chose at random.

Comment: you are welcome…

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to use [`StateSpaceModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html) to implement the solution, you could do the following

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel[
  {x1'[t] == Pi x2[t],
   x2'[t] == Pi (-a - b Cos[2 t]) x1[t] - d Pi x2[t]},
  {{x1[t], 0}, {x2[t], 0}, {x1'[t], 0}, {x2'[t], 0}},
  {{u[t], 0}},
  {x1[t], x2[t]},
  t
  ]
```

> [image]

Then find the [`StateResponse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateResponse.html)

```
response = StateResponse[{ssm, {1, 2}}, {UnitStep[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> Out: {InterpolatingFunction[][t], InterpolatingFunction[][t]}

And then [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) it

```
ParametricPlot[response, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> [image]